Read ase trajectory file by another (free) software
ase produces nice trajectory file, .traj. However, only "ase gui" can read  the ".traj" file.
Is there another (free) sofware that can be used for reading ase traj-files ?

You can always convert .traj file to other formats (for example .xyz) to visualize in other softwares.
